# How to create responsive video in Bootstrap-5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a two column layout, and wish to have a video in the first column, and an image in the second which are responsive.
I have tried several options, and the image works well, however, the video is not responsive.
The best result I have been able to create is to not have width/height attributes for the video.

```
                       <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 order-first">
                                        <div class="card">
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mEQ8NJsAowg" title="Player One" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                        <h5 class="card-title">196</h5>
                                                        <input type="number" name="playerOneAddScore" id="playerOneAddScore">
                                                        <p class="card-text">
                                                        </p>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="card">
                                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1280x720/000/fff&text=Test+image" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="Player Two">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                                <h5 class="card-title">196</h5>
                                                        <input type="number" name="playerOneAddScore" id="playerOneAddScore">
                                                        <p class="card-text">
                                                        </p>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div><!-- end row -->
```

Fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yabk2zxv/)

Comment: Bootstrap 5 has responsive classes for different aspect ratios, including [videos](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/).

Comment: The HTML isn't properly structured one of the cols are missing a close tag

Answer (score -1):

Rich.
Bang on the money.
By add the class ratio, and, ratio-16x9 I was able to achieve the desired responsive video.
This did come with some unexpected behavior with other element within the card, however, this may be a result of my choice of container (card).
But, I will address that in a new question.
Thanks

```
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 order-first">
                            <div class="card ratio ratio-16x9">
                                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mEQ8NJsAowg" title="Player One" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                            <h5 class="card-title">196</h5>
                                            <input type="number" name="playerOneAddScore" id="playerOneAddScore">
                                            <p class="card-text">Something here
                                            </p>
                                    </div><!-- end card-body -->
                            </div><!-- end card -->
                    </div><!-- col-sm-6 -->

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="card">
                                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1280x720/000/fff&text=Test+image" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="Player Two">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                            <h5 class="card-title">196</h5>
                                                    <input type="number" name="playerTwoAddScore" id="playerTwoAddScore">
                                                    <p class="card-text">Something here
                                                    </p>
                                    </div><!-- end card-body -->
                            </div><!-- end card -->
                    </div><!-- col-sm-6 -->
            </div><!-- end row -->
```